# Offset hrule while parskip=true

Tags: spacing, titles, rules, parskip

So what I'm trying to do is similar to this [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317437/how-to-control-the-offset-of-hrules-and-spacing-of-the-text-following-a-hrule), which is to surround the title and subtitle of the document with 2 similarly distanced `\hrule`. If i follow their description it works wonderful. However: When i set the document class in `parskip=full` mode (personal preference), the linked article doesn't do the trick anymore and I couldn't figure out why. 
The MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass[parskip=full, paper=a4, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% DOCUMENT 
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{centering}
        {\Large Institution \par} 
        {\Large Department} 
        \vspace{4cm}
        \hrule 
        \vspace{.3cm}
        {\Huge\bfseries \textsc  Title} \par
        {\Large \bfseries Subtitle} \par 
        \vspace{.3cm}
        \hrule 
    \end{centering}
    \par
    \blindtext 
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The outcome is this
[image: MWE]
So as you can see, the distance between the top line and the title isn't the same as the distance between the subtitle and the bottom line. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust me, you don't want to use the parskip.

But, if you insist, make it zero where necessary.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full, paper=a4, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% DOCUMENT 
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
{\Large Institution\par}
{\Large Department\par}
\vspace{4cm}
\hrule 
\vspace{.3cm}
{\Huge\bfseries  Title\par}
{\Large\bfseries Subtitle\par}
\vspace{.3cm}
\hrule 
\end{center}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

There is no `centering` environment. Add vertical spaces where you deem them necessary.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the advise, but may i ask why i should avoid the parskip portion?

Comment: @Hoerbii3 It makes reading more difficult. It's possibly good for short texts, not for longer documents. But it's a matter of opinion, backed by some renowned typographers such as Jan Tschichold.

Comment: Ok, so I thought. In my native language it is unusual to see the indents after a paragraph and i prefer no indets aswell. I think i will manually work with `\noindent` or a workaround solution. And again, thanks!

Comment: @Hoerbii3 Well, neither parskip nor indent is really bad.